# Appending data- to a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following `data` types on my `<li>` `data-author` and `data-body`.

When the `li` is clicked I would like to append the `data-author` and the `data-info` to a couple of `div` classes for example `classOne` and `classTwo`.

What would be the best way to get the `data-` when clicked and pass the data to its required location?

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url = "assets/js/data.json",
        fetchJSON = $.getJSON(url);

    fetchJSON.done(function(response) {
        var buttons = response.map(function(i) {
            return $('<li>').html(i.title).attr({
                "data-author": i.author,
                "data-body": i.body
            })
        });
        $('ul').append(buttons);

    });

    $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){


    });
}); //Ready function closed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the `data-...` attribute from the `this` element.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    var author = $this.attr("data-author");
    var body = $this.attr("data-body");

    $('div.classOne').text(author);
    $('div.classTwo').text(body);
});
```

Note you can generate the list even with a shorter code:

```
var buttons = response.map(function(i) {
   return $('<li>', {
     text: i.title,
     "data-author": i.author,
     "data-body": i.body
   })
});
```

If you want to add the attributes, in DOM, do not use `data()` since that will store them in the dom element. Otherwise, you can use it, and the fields are accessible by `$this.data("author")` and `$this.data("body")`.

```js
var response = [
  { title: "Hello World!", author: "Someone", body: "Hi there!" },
  { title: "Hello Mars!", author: "Another One", body: "Greetings!" }
];

var buttons = response.map(function(i) {
   return $('<li>', {
     text: i.title,
     "data-author": i.author,
     "data-body": i.body
   })
 });

$("ul").html(buttons);
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  var author = $this.attr("data-author");
  var body = $this.attr("data-body");

  $('div.author').text(author);
  $('div.body').text(body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<div class="author"></div>
<div class="body"></div>
```

Comment: I can not say thanks enough to the quality of your answer very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $('div.classOne').html($(this).data('author'));
    $('div.classTwo').html($(this).data('body'));
});
```

```js
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('div.classOne').html($(this).data('author'));
  $('div.classTwo').html($(this).data('body'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-author="Rohan" data-body="Lorem ipsum doner inut">List 1</li>
  <li data-author="Andrew" data-body="Oh, Again Lorem ipsum doner inut">List 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="classOne"></div>
<div class="classTwo"></div>
```